# Proving a sign rule for $f_{2n}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, fa.functional-analysis, permutations

If $t_{1},...,t_{n}$ are real numbers, consider the set of indexed linear operators $T(t_{1}),...,T(t_{n})$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and define its ordering by:
$$\pi[T(t_{1})\cdots T(t_{n})] := \operatorname{sign}(\pi)T(\pi^{-1}(1))\cdots T(\pi^{-1}(n)),$$
where $\pi^{1}(1) \ge \pi^{-1}(2) \ge \cdots \ge \pi^{-1}(n)$ orders the $t$ variables from biggest to smallest.

If $v \in \mathcal{H}$ is fixed and $n$ is even, one can define:
$$f_{n}(t_{1},...,t_{n}) = (-1)^{\frac{n}{2}}\langle v, \pi[T(t_{1})T(t_{2})\cdots T(t_{n})] v\rangle $$
where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the inner product on $\mathcal{H}$.

Given $2n$ real variables $t_{1},\bar{t}_{1},t_{2},\bar{t}_{2},...,t_{n},\bar{t}_{n}$, I want to study $f_{2n}(t_{1},\bar{t}_{1},t_{2},\bar{t}_{2},...,t_{n},\bar{t}_{n})$. For this, suppose $T(t_{1})$  has a decomposition $T(t_{1}) = T^{+}(t_{1}) + T^{-}(t_{1})$. Moreover, if $\{A,B\} := AB+BA$, assume the following anti-commutation relations:
$$\{T^{+}(t_{1}),T(t_{k})\}= \{T^{-}(t_{1}),T(t_{k})\} = 0 \quad \{T^{+}(t_{1}),\bar{T}(\bar{t}_{k})\} = -a_{1k} \quad \{T^{-}(t_{1}),\bar{T}(\bar{t}_{k})\} = a_{1k} $$
The $a_{1k}$'s are just numbers.

If $T^{+}(t_{1})v = 0$ and the adjoint of $T^{-}(t_{1})$ applied to $v$ is also zero, then one can use the anti-commutation relations above to write $f$ as:
$$
f_{2n}(x_{1},\bar{x}_{1},x_{2},\bar{x}_{2},...,x_{n},\bar{x}_{n}) = \overbrace{\pm\langle v, T^{-}(x_{1})T^{\#}\cdots T^{\#}v\rangle}^{=0} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\varepsilon_{k}a_{ik}f_{2(n-1)}(t_{2},\bar{t}_{1},t_{3},...,\hat{\bar{t}}_{k},t_{k+2},...,\bar{t}_{n}) \pm \overbrace{\langle v, T^{\#}\cdots T^{\#}T^{+}(t_{1})v\rangle}^{=0}$$
The notation $T^{\#}$ means some $T$ or $\bar{T}$ and the $\hat{\bar{t}}_{k}$ means this index is omitted. In other words, one decomposes $T(t_{1})$ as a sum of $T^{\pm}(t_{1})$ and moves $T^{+}(t_{1})$ to the last position on the right and $T^{-}(t_{1})$ to the first position on the left by using anti-commutations. We get a sign at each movement.

Here comes my question. I worked out some explicit examples and I always get the sign $\varepsilon_{k}$ to be $(-1)^{k+1}$. However, I can't prove this as a rule. Is this a rule?